# Loading a view outside of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view that generates a dynamic navigation bar.

Within Codeigniter, I just load the View normally with `$this->load->view('navigation');`

I'm integrating my app with another PHP app that doesn't use Codeigniter and I would like to use the same Navigation bar.

My navigation View is just a unordered list navigation with logic for user's security access and active class css styling.  Which is the reason I don't want to recode the navigation again.

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="main">Main</li>
    ...
    <li><a href="second">Second Page</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to call up Codeigntier from an external php script and load a view?  Similar to an include.

Comment: What is the other app's framework? How are the other apps views setup? Does the other app use the ***exact*** same security scheme? or is it exclusive to codeigniter?

Comment: The other app uses its own framework.  The security scheme just looks up sql table and load up the <li> anchor accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view is just a php file with some variables in place, as long as the other app generates the proper variables needed for the security logic and information needed in the view, just [include it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) like any other php file.